# About List.map usage

Tags: list, ocaml

List.map is of type

```
- : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

It's easy for me to understand the following code:

```
List.map (fun x -> x+1) [1;2;3;4];;
```

which adds 1 to each element of the list so it returns the following list :

```
- : int list = [2;3;4;5]
```

Now this is in an exercise where I'm asked to indicate the type of this :

```
List.map (fun p -> p 7) [ (fun n m -> n + m) ];;
```

I don't understand at all what it means to be honest. 
What does p 7 mean ?
Why is there a function in the list ?

The type is

```
- : (int -> int) list = [<fun>]
```

But I can't understand why.
What does it mean when fun is between brackets ?

Thank you.

Comment: Take time to read documentation of Ocaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `p 7` mean?

It means the [*application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_application) of function `p`  to argument `7` .... You might spend some time reading the wikipage on [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) (at least to learn about functional *abstraction*)

Read also about [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

> Why is there a function in the list ?

In Ocaml, functions are values, so you can have list of functions. If it was not a list of functions, you'll get a typing error. If you think more, you can understand what kind of functions are allowed.

> What does it mean when `fun` is between brackets ?

The toplevel is not able to print functional values (implemented as [*closures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))). It shows them as `<fun>`. For a simpler example, pass `fun x -> x+1;;` (then try also `fun y -> y;;`)  to your [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

<sup>(the rest of the exercise is left to the reader)</sup>

Comment: I already understand application, lambda-calulus and currying, that wasn't the problem... but I admit that I wasn't clear enough in my question. What was bothering me was the function inside the list, I had never encountered that situation before so for some reason I thought the usual reasoning wouldn't apply. Anyway now I understand that the way it is written it means that n is 7, the first int is m and the second int is the return type of (fun n m -> n + m).

Comment: An example of something "useful" would be : let f x = List.map (fun p -> p 7 x) [ (fun n m -> n + m); (fun a b -> a * b);;        f 4;;